# Exporting and Importing ABAP Classes

Tags: abap, netweaver

I have around 10 classes I want to export to another system. Transporting isn't an option and I was wondering if there is a faster way to copy the classes. Manually creating and filling up the classes would take quite long.

Most questions around this topic are from 5+ years ago and I was wondering what the best method is. I've read some nice things about [SAPlink](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/SAPlink) and I imagine this is the way to go?

Comment: on the page of SAPlink : "please use **[abapGit](https://github.com/larshp/abapGit)** from now on" (approximately).

Comment: There's always been a way to import local classes as global and I am almost sure that there has been something developed to do it the other way round, however I cannot find this function at the moment...

Comment: @SandraRossi, could you turn this into an answer? It is the best option, from my point of view.

Comment: @MatthijsMennens, 10 classes aren't much. You can easily copy-paste them by hand by using the *source code based* editor in SE80 or the Eclipse-based *ABAP Development Tools*. Both editors enable you to copy _all_ of the classes' code with simpe Ctrl+A-Ctrl+C key presses. ADT might even enable you to copy the whole classes by opening both systems side by side in the project view.

Comment: @Florian, I know 10 classes are very doable, but I was just wondering if there wasn't a better way to do this. I'll try SandraRossi's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already mentioned in the comments, but I give you some details and some screenshots:

Go to the source system, start SE24 and switch to the Source Code Based

[image]

Mark the code (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C) and go to the target system.

Start SE24 and create the class, switch to "Source Code Based" and paste the code.